# Можно ли вставить видео в SFML?

Tags: c++, видео, sfml

Можно ли вставлять видео в *SFML*, если да, то как?
Если нетрудно, то кодом или ссылку.
В документации *SFML* не могу найти, хотя, возможно, я просто плохо ищу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *SFML* нет встроенной возможности для работы с видео файлами. Быстрый гуглинг нашел пару библиотек, расширяющих возможности *SFML* в этой части:

- [sfeMovie](http://sfemovie.yalir.org/latest/)
- [Motion](https://github.com/zsbzsb/Motion)

Обе они основаны на библиотеке [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/about.html). Актуальность требует проверки.